# Using Natural Language Processing, how can we add our own Stop Words to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I am testing the library below, based on this code sample:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS
from collections import Counter

df_new = pd.DataFrame(['okay', 'yeah', 'thank', 'im'])
stop_words = text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS.union(df_new)
#stop_words

w_counts = Counter(w for w in ' '.join(df['text_without_stopwords']).split() if w.lower() not in stop_words)


df_words = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(w_counts, orient='index').reset_index()
df_words.columns = ['word','count']


import seaborn as sns
# selecting top 20 most frequent words
d = df_words.nlargest(columns="count", n = 25) 
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
ax = sns.barplot(data=d, x= "word", y = "count")
ax.set(ylabel = 'Count')
plt.show()
```

I'm seeing this chart.

[image]

I'm trying to add these words to stop words: 'okay', 'yeah', 'thank', 'im'

But...they are all coming through!! What's wrong here??

Comment: Are you just trying to append new words in the "ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS" list?

Comment: *to add custom words to a list of stop words* - you're not adding new words to a list of stopwords, you just filtering out words that are **not** in `ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS`

Comment: Yes, yes, how do I append new words in the "ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS" list?

Comment: @ASH, is that `df` used for any other purposes except for df.nlargest ?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to add specific words to 'ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS' from sklearn, and take the result of that and plot the top 25 frequency/count of words.

Comment: @ASH, ok, could `all_words` contain duplicate words ?

Comment: It definitely contains duplicates. After filtering out all ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS, I want to plot the frequencies of the remaining words in the dataframe. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of join all the filtered words into `io.StringIO` buffer and loading it to a dataframe, a much more straightforward/quick way is using `collections.Counter` with its [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) function to get word counts right away:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS
from collections import Counter

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'text_without_stopwords': ['my stop text hex words',
                                              'with some stop boards words', 'stop text']})
w_counts = Counter(w for w in ' '.join(df['text_without_stopwords']).split()
                   if w.lower() not in ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS)
plt.bar(*zip(*w_counts.most_common(25)))
plt.xticks(rotation=60)
plt.show()
```

---

Sample plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think this is close. I updated my code, based on your code sample. The words that are supposed to be stopped, are actually coming through. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try to creates w_counts to exclude the words in df_new, I think the issue with your code it you creating df_new containing the words that you want to add to the stop words list, but you are not actually removing these words.

```
stop_words = ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS.union(['okay', 'yeah', 'thank', 'im'])
w_counts = Counter(w for w in ' '.join(df['text_without_stopwords']).split() if w.lower() not in stop_words)
```